# Merging two Makefiles to build one output

Tags: c, makefile, operating-system

I have a simple OS which has its own `makefile` to build its `floppy` as output and the `picoc` (a tiny c compiler) which also has its own `Makefile` to built its own executable output file.

Now I want to move this "picoc" to my OS which means I should move all the files to my OS and build the app inside my OS files and `make` the OS and get one output as `floppy` which has the `picoc` included. Now I have no idea how to merge these two makefiles together? (I'm not good at make files at all).

Now the question is: is there anyway I can merge these two apps by merging the makefiles?

I've read the related topics about my problem but none of them was about my case.

Comment: You want to include the `picoc` compiler in your built OS image?

Comment: yes its exactly what i want to do

Comment: So you don't need to combine the makefiles as such. What you need to do is add the path to `picoc` to the appropriate place in your makefile and add a recipe to your makefile which runs the `picoc` makefile to build it.

Comment: could you please go to more details ?!

Comment: Do you understand how makefiles work? You effectively want something like [Overriding Part of Another Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding-Makefiles) only you aren't trying to override another makefile just use it for your `picoc` target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be something along the lines:

```
floppy: picoc
    command to make floppy

picoc:
    make -C directory/of/picoc all
.PHONY : picoc
```

This is more for guidelines then full solution, because I'm not sure if I understood your project structure.

Comment: With recursive makefiles - for those insisting on using these - it is often a good idea to use phony targets and force the recursion. In your example, as soon as `picoc` gets created, the recursion won't happen ever again.

Comment: now i've encountered another problem . now i have the file in my os image , i can include them but when i want to call a function from the picoc libraries it wont alloy me to do that . it says undefined refrence to <function name> . where is the problem ?

Comment: Not sure, but is it properly loaded/linked? Also have a feeling that it should be asked separately.